# Mysql2 Error on Rails Migration

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

On `rake db:migrate` I get the error:

> Mysql2::Error: Can't read dir of
>   './site_development/' (errno:
>   13): SHOW TABLES

Current versions of installed shenanigans:

From MySQL install bundle: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.12, for osx10.6 (i386) using readline 5.1

From RVM: ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin10.7.0];
Rails 3.0.7; Mysql2 0.2.7

I'm aware certain permissions need to be updated, but I'm not quite sure which ones.

Answer (score 4):

Is your database named `site_development` by any chance? If so, this might help:

Determine what your mysql data directory is. For me, it is `/usr/local/mysql/data`. `sudo ls -l` that bad-boy. I bet you'll find a directory named `site_development` that is owned by `root` (or some user other than the `_mysql` user). For me, all the mysql data dirs are owned by `_mysql:wheel`. Do you have another database that is working properly? See what the ownership on that table is in the `data` directory, and make sure that `site_development` matches.

I suspect that if you run `mysql` from the command line, and try to select something from a table in that database, you'll see a similar error. If not, let us know what your db name is, what the permissions are on your mysql data directory.

If you're not sure where your mysql data dir is, try typing `which mysql`. That should show you where the mysql binary is, it should be in a `PATH_PREFIX/mysql/bin/mysql` director. The data directory should be a sibling of `bin`, so it would be `PATH_PREFIX/mysql/data`.

Comment: The database is site development.  I can see it in the same mysql data directory that you mentioned above. The two users with default permissions are $USER and wheel.  Permissions look the same across all databases I created with mysql.  Site_development is the first db that is part of a rails test project.

Comment: Interesting. So, if you run `mysql -u RAILS_DB_USER -p site_development` and enter the passsword for your rails user (just like it is listed in `database.yml`), can you select from tables in that database?

Comment: Yep. Sequel Pro is working too. But apparently, the "database doesn't exist" even though I can see it listed on "SHOW DATABASES;".

Comment: Maybe the `site_development` has proper permissions, but the contents of it don't? Try `sudo ls -l /MYSQL/DATA/PATH/site_development`. Make sure each file in there has the same permissions. If not you can `sudo chown -R $USER:wheel MYSQL/DATA/PATH/site_development`

Answer (score 0):

For Mac OS, run

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql*
```

User mysql should have write access to mysql data directory.